# How to reference one object to another?

Tags: python, oop, object

I'm still new to python programming language. Could you please explain me how to reference one object to another. For example from the below code, I need to add friends to each object. However, friends of the object are objects of person.

ie. XYZ has friends ABC, LMN where ABC, LMN are Person Object.

Below is my code example

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def add_friend(self,friend):
        pass #friend is a reference to another person object.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l_ist = [Person('XYZ'),Person('ABC'),Person('LMN')]
```

Comment: It shouldn't be complicated. An object can have a list attribute called `friends` which is a list of objects of the same class. Create this list as an empty list at initialization (unless you want your objects to be narcissists who are friends with themselves).

Comment: Your object will need an attribute to hold the friends, of which there can be zero or more in no particular order (sounds like a list). And when you create a new person, they have no friends until you add them, so you know how to initialise the attribute in the `__init__()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add the name to the friend list, to add direct object reference, do `self.friends.append(l_ist[1])`

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = []

    def add_friend(self,friend):
        self.friends.append(friend)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l_ist = [Person('XYZ'),Person('ABC'),Person('LMN')]

    x = l_ist[0] 
    x.add_friend(l_ist[1].name)
    x.add_friend(l_ist[2].name)
    #  to add the object itself to friend list do `x.add_friend(l_ist[2])` ,
    # to just add only name do `x.add_friend(l_ist[2].name)`

    print(x.friends) # PRINT ['ABC', 'LMN']
```

Comment: Worth noting that this adds strings as friends, not references to `Person` objects

Comment: @Oliver.R updated the solution, add details to add object itself not the object property

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how your `Person` class has a `name` attribute, you could give it a `friends` attribute which is a list of their friends. This list could store the `Person` attributes passed in as friends.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = []

    def add_friend(self,friend):
        self.friends.append(friend)  #friend is a reference to another person object.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l_ist = [Person('XYZ'),Person('ABC'),Person('LMN')]
    l_ist[0].add_friend(l_ist[1])
    l_ist[0].add_friend(l_ist[2])
    print(l_ist[0].friends)
    print([f.name for f in l_ist[0].friends])
```

Comment: Yeah this was understanding. Just one more doubt. what if we had more person object and we want to add_friend using their name and not index in the list, as we would not know the index of a particular person.

Comment: You could iterate through the list and check each `person.name` to see if it matches, and if so, `add_friend(person)`. You could even make a `PersonRegister` class that contains all the `Person` objects created and can easily search them using functions that include this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. You were very helpful means a lot.

Comment: If an answer or a comment helps, please upvote them, and if an answer solves your issue, please accept it as the correct asnwer so that people can know that the issue has been solved and no more effort needs to be expended here!

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is treated as object. To add a friend in your code, you could just add:

l_ist[0].add_friend(l_ist[1])

To store the friends in a list within the person instance itself, you could add:

self.friends = []

And then within the add_friends method:

self.friends.append(friend)